# Cannot get Google Drive API v3 to return nextPageToken,incompleteSearch,files

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

**MAJOR EDIT**
This entire post is the result of a pilot error.   There was a python function within another function that was extracting *only* the `files` key from the returned response.  This was completely missed.  The program works fine.  The answer below is correct.

---

I know that as of v3,

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
```

returns only an array of much smaller docs with name, id, etc.  If I change this to:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files
or
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files(id,name,createdTime,size)
```

it works; I get back loads of detailed information.  But I cannot seem to find the right incantation to get it to emit a *single* doc that includes `nextPageToken` and `incompleteSearch` along with the *array* of `files`.   I was hoping

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=nextPageToken,files(id,name,createdTime,size)
```

would work but it does not.  In fact,

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=nextPageToken
```

yields an empty array (but return code 200).  I'd really like to get:

```
{
   nextPageToken: ...
   incompleteSearch: ...
   files: [
      {id,name,createdTime,size},
      {id,name,createdTime,size}
   ]
}
```

This is all going through `requests` and the OAuth2 bearer token setup is fine.

**EDIT**
The solution below works as described when called directly on the command line from curl.   But from a python program using requests, it does not.
More to come on this….

Answer (score 3):

In your situation, how about the following field value?

```
incompleteSearch,nextPageToken,files(id,name,createdTime,size)
```

When this is reflected in the endpoint of "Method: files.list", it becomes as follows. In this case, the query parameter is used with the URL encoding. Please be careful about this.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=incompleteSearch%2CnextPageToken%2Cfiles(id%2Cname%2CcreatedTime%2Csize)
```

- By this endpoint, the following result is returned.

  ```json
  {
    "nextPageToken": "###",
    "incompleteSearch": ###,
    "files": [
      {
        "size": "12345",
        "id": "###",
        "name": "###",
        "createdTime": "2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      ,
      ,
      ,
    ]
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [REST Resource: files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files)
- [Method: files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list)

Comment: Apols; clicked down arrow by accident.

Comment: @Buzz Moschetti About `Apols; clicked down arrow by accident.`, you can undo the downvote. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294938/how-can-i-undo-my-vote But, if the undo cannot be done by the lock, please tell me. In that case, when I modified the answer, you can undo the downvote. If that cannot be done, please tell me. I can post it as a new answer.

Comment: @Buzz Moschetti I'm worried that in the current stage, the undo of the downvote might have been locked. So, I modified my answer. Please confirm whether you can undo the downvote.

Comment: @Buzz Moschetti About `It worked; I was able to upvote to reverse my click.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer